# YARN: what should I configure for 3 nodes?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hadoop-yarn

Here is my setup:

node1 - resourcemanager
node1,node2,node3 - nodemanager

What should I specify in yarn-site.xml in node1, node2 and node3? I dont know which port I should use. Do I have to specify port?

Answer (score 0):

All the basic settings can be the same in yarn-site.xml throughout your cluster.

`yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address` should point to your master (node1), port can be anything you want (8031 seems to be the default). Same goes for `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address` - default port seems to be 8030. But yes, you should define these values and set the port.